# Finding a pattern in a matrix in any order?

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

This is a question which I worked upon. The target was to find pattern in a two dimensional matrix of letters. The catch is that I should be able to find the pattern even if it occurs

1. across rows
2. across columns
3. along the

diagonals.

Let the matrix be

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N O P
```

I wrote a C program by taking the matrix as an an array of character pointers and used the substring (`strstr`) to find the pattern. I partially succeeded. I was able to look for any substring which occurs continously in the linearized matrix.But then I hit the roadblock with the diagonal elements and cross elements. By cross elements I mean

```
A  
B E  
I F C etc.
```

I am sure that some algorithm will be there which will do a brute force to find out any pattern in a simple 2D matrix. But I am not able to conceive it after hours of struggle.

Please suggest a method to approach this issue in C. I know using scripting and text based approach this will be an easy one, but I am looking for a algo which can be implemented in C.

p.s This is no home work problem or work assignment. I am curious to know   that's all.

Comment: start by applying your linearised algorithm to the transpose of the matrix to get column-matches (assuming input is row-major) and similarly to the linearisation of the diagonal and cross elements. generalise and condense after you have achieved that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it storing the grid in a 2-dimensional array of `char` as there are less boundary conditions to worry about (such as `char *`'s pointing to strings of different lengths). Anyway, here is the result. The grid used in this example was "borrowed" from [Types of Dog Word Search](http://thewordsearch.com/puzzle/9/types-of-dog/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void findword(const char *word, const char *grid, int rows, int cols)
{
    int len = strlen(word);
    int xdir, ydir, xstart, ystart, xend, yend, xpos, ypos, pos, step, i;

    for (xdir = -1; xdir <= 1; xdir++) {
        xstart = xdir < 0 ? len - 1 : 0;
        xend = xdir > 0 ? cols - len : cols - 1;
        if (xend < xstart)
            continue;
        for (ydir = -1; ydir <= 1; ydir++) {
            if (ydir == 0 && xdir == 0)
                continue;
            ystart = ydir < 0 ? len - 1 : 0;
            yend = ydir > 0 ? rows - len : rows -1;
            if (yend < ystart)
                continue;
            for (xpos = xstart; xpos <= xend; xpos++) {
                for (ypos = ystart; ypos <= yend; ypos++) {
                    pos = ypos * cols + xpos;
                    step = ydir * cols + xdir;
                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        if (word[i] != grid[pos])
                            break;
                        pos += step;
                    }
                    if (i == len) {
                        printf("Found %s at row %d, column %d, dir %s%s\n",
                                word, ypos + 1, xpos + 1,
                                ydir < 0 ? "north" : ydir > 0 ? "south" : "",
                                xdir < 0 ? "west" : xdir > 0 ? "east" : "");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#define GRID_COLS 14
#define GRID_ROWS (sizeof(wordgrid) / sizeof(wordgrid[0]))

static const char wordgrid[][GRID_COLS] = {
    "ESULBULLDOGHER",
    "EDHISHLSRUDSRE",
    "IARELIEWTTORRE",
    "RLGTLAEITCORGI",
    "EMRDERIISLEPCF",
    "HARSCANHHHLEHF",
    "CTREDOETOEGBII",
    "SIETLPLUHEATHT",
    "NAITHXNLAUECUS",
    "INRELDEEIBBOAA",
    "PNRREOADREHGHM",
    "UDEAAERHIAFRUI",
    "BRTOBOXERHTSAI",
    "LELAMSLRLHUDRL"
};

#define NUM_WORDS (sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]))

static const char * const words[] = {
    "CHIHUAHUA", "BULLDOG", "TERRIER", "COLLIE", "SHEPHERD", "BOXER",
    "HOUND", "BEAGLE", "CORGI", "ROTTWEILER", "PINSCHER", "DALMATIAN",
    "SETTER", "MASTIFF"
};

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    printf("Grid:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < GRID_ROWS; i++)
        printf("%.*s\n", GRID_COLS, wordgrid[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_WORDS; i++) {
        printf("*** Looking for %s ***\n", words[i]);
        findword(words[i], &wordgrid[0][0], GRID_ROWS, GRID_COLS);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are probably more efficient algorithms, such as searching the grid for the first letter of the word and then checking the eight directions for the remaining letters of the word (with impossible directions filtered out according to grid position and word length).

Comment: I checked this code,This is working extremely well.Kudos

Answer (score 2):

(I'm calling this pseudocode - massing the matrix, etc in this way is incorrect.)

```
int match(char** matrix, int width, int height, int x, int y, char *str, int strPos, int strLen, int dx, int dy)
{

    if (strPos == strLen)
        return 1;

    int i = x + dx;
    int j = y + dy;

    if (i < 0 || i >= width || j < 0 || j >= height || strPos > strLen)
        return 0;

    /// fix this...
    char mc = matrix[x][y];

    if (mc != str[strPos])
        return 0;

    return match(matrix, width, height, i, j, str, strPos + 1, strLen, dx, dy);
}

int matches(char** matrix, int width, int height, char* str, int strLen)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixWidth; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixHeight; ++j)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] != str[0])
                continue;

            for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; ++dx)
            {
                for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; ++dy)
                {
                    if (match(matrix, matrixWidth, matrixHeight, i, j, dx, dy))
                        return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;



}
```

This is probably missing some bounds checks, and could be optimized by only checking a direction (dx,dy) if it's possible for the string to fit without going outside of the matrix bounds.

This is very similar to a flood fill, with the additional constraint that checks must go in a single direction from the initial recursive call, rather than spiraling out.